# API endpoint change effective 1/1/2016

Tags: integration

I received notice of API endpoint change effective 1/1/2016. How can I know if this would affect me and what is the best way to know what all changes I have to make.

This is not related to tls change but the saleforce endpoint change only.

So lets say I have hardcoded this www.salesforce.com in plenty of times within my java code, do I need to change it everywhere manually or is there a better way?

Any help would be much appreciated !!!

Comment: Are you referring to the end of TLS 1 support?

Comment: could be the retiring of www..salesforce.com as a valid api endpoint as well

Comment: Its not TLS support but just the salesforce endpoint address. With hardcoding done in our java code , as justwonerig i tere is a better way than doing mnually.

Answer (score 2):

Answers are in the email:

> What is changing?
>
> Currently, customers can use
> https://www.salesforce.com
> as an API endpoint that will route them to the
> correct instance. As of January 1, 2016, the internal routing will be
> retired, and any API endpoints will need to be changed
>
> Note: This only applies to API traffic; logging in from a browser by
> clicking “login” will still work.
>
> Why are we retiring the internal routing?
>
> This change is to ensure we focus our development efforts on
> delivering better performance and higher availability on the dedicated
> API endpoints.
>
> **What action do I need to take?**
>
> Update your integrations to replace
> https://www.salesforce.com
>
> with
> https://login.salesforce.com
>
> as the official endpoint for the Salesforce API.
>
> **What will happen if I do not take action?**
>
> The API will no longer function, and your API calls will result in a
> “404 (Page Not Found)” error.
>
> How can I get more information?
>
> For additional questions, you can open a case with Customer Support
> via the Help & Training portal.

Comment: Hi Eric thanks for looking into this. So do we need to make manual changes all the way to our java code. We have hardcoded this which is not good practice but this is the way it was done by previous developers.

Answer (score 1):

This endpoint change would effect your org integration's through any ETL tools or real time, that are using the Old salesforce API endpoint to make calls to salesforce. You need to update this URL or salesforce API endpoint in all your integrations. All your integration's will run as usual after you make these changes.

Comment: Thanks for that. I just wanted to confirm if i had a better way than manual update.